# Using Rebus in a multi tenant application

Tags: rebus

How would you use rebus in a multi tenant application?

Would you choose:

- a rebus queue for all tenants together or
- a rebus queue (input / error) per tenant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about the context of your question :)

But I think I would prefer one message queue that processes the messages, and then pass around the tenant ID as a custom header on all relevant messages.

In fact, some of my colleagues are doing just that right now.

A few things turn out to be nifty when you want to pass around this kind of information in a header - i.e. I can recommend that you automatically transfer the tenant ID to outgoing messages by doing somethings like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
   .(...)
   .Events(e => {
       e.MessageSent += (bus, dest, msg) => {
           if (!MessageContext.HasCurrent) return;

           var items = MessageContext.GetCurrent().Items;
           if (!items.ContainsKey("custom-tenant-id")) return;

           bus.AttachHeader(msg, "custom-tenant-id", items["custom-tenant-id"]);
       };
   })
   .(...)
```

thus allowing for exchanging messages while not having to worry about the tenant ID along the way.